# Split into multiple files by using unique columns in a unix file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have requirement to split below file (`sample.csv`) into multiple files by using the unique columns (first 3 are unique columns)

sample.csv

```
123|22|56789|ABCDEF|12AB34|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|443.3400|1|1
123|12|5679|BCDEFG|34CD56|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|896.7200|1|2
123|12|5679|CDEFGH|45DE67|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|680.9200|1|1
123|22|56789|DEFGHI|56EF78|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|405.8800|1|2
```

#### Required output files should be as below

sample_123_22_56789.csv

```
123|22|56789|ABCDEF|12AB34|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|443.3400|1|1
123|22|56789|DEFGHI|56EF78|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|405.8800|1|2
```

sample_123_12_5679.csv

```
123|12|5679|BCDEFG|34CD56|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|896.7200|1|2
123|12|5679|CDEFGH|45DE67|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|680.9200|1|1
```

I am using below command and it is working but want to make it generic instead of hard coding the `$4"|"$5"|"$6"|"$7"|"$8"|"$9"|"$10`

```
awk -F\| '{print $4"|"$5"|"$6"|"$7"|"$8"|"$9"|"$10 > 
 sample_"$1"_"$2"_"$3".CSV"}' sample.csv
```

#### Update #1

Thank you for the reply and sorry for the confusion, my desired output would be as below, (Excluding first 3 columns).

sample_123_22_56789.csv

```
ABCDEF|12AB34|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|443.3400|1|1 DEFGHI|56EF78|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|405.8800|1|2
```

sample_123_12_5679.csv

```
BCDEFG|34CD56|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|896.7200|1|2 CDEFGH|45DE67|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|680.9200|1|1
```

Comment: What do you mean by generic? What can change?

Comment: This is a variation (generalisation) of the recent question "[Create an array in data file while the value in a specific column is constant](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/530132)", and a few other older ones.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean by "generic" is that the number of columns can change and you always want to write all of them to a file whose name is defined by the 1st 3 fields, then you can try this:

```
awk -F\| '{
            data=$4
            for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){
                data = data"|"$(i)
            }
            print data > "sample_"$1"_"$2"_"$3".CSV"}' sample.csv
```

Of course, that does what your command is doing. This doesn't produce the desired output as shown in your question, but that's because the desired output doesn't match your command. If you want to include *all* fields in the output, as you show in your example, use this instead:

```
awk -F\| '{
            data=$1
            for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
                data = data"|"$(i)
            }
            print data > "sample_"$1"_"$2"_"$3".CSV"}' sample.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine

```
for i in `awk -F "|" '{if (!seen[$2]++)print $2}' file2.txt `; do awk -v i="$i" -F "|" '$2==i{print $0}' file2.txt >sample_123_"$i"_56789.csv; done
```

output

```
praveen:~$ cat sample_123_22_56789.csv 
123|22|56789|ABCDEF|12AB34|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|443.3400|1|1
123|22|56789|DEFGHI|56EF78|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|405.8800|1|2


 cat sample_123_12_56789.csv 
123|12|5679|BCDEFG|34CD56|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|896.7200|1|2
123|12|5679|CDEFGH|45DE67|2019-07-10|2019-07-10|680.9200|1|1
```